# Does Android GridLayout automatically fills empty cells (or rows)?

Tags: android, android-gridlayout

I'm trying to make an Activity where I display music calendaritems for a day. At a certain time, only 2 calendar items can be added. The calendaritems at the 2 columns can have different start times and duration.

To display these items, I use a GridLayout with 2 columns and 48rows (each item can be added at every half hour = 24h * 2)

To test this, I added 3 calendar items which I add programmatically to the grid layout. The calculated row and column properties are added (these are correct in my opinion):

- Hitparade: 00.00 - 01.00 : startRow = 0, rowspan = 2 (duration is 1h), column = 0
- 2010-2015: 00.00 - 01.00 : startRow = 0, rowspan = 2 (duration is 1h), column = 1
- Nederlandstalig: 01.30 - 03.30: startRow = 3, rowspan = 4 (duration is 2h), column = 0

With this data, I assume there should be an empty row with index 2. There is no item planned from 01.00 - 01.30. But the layout of my grid layout is this:

[image]

So the calendar item 'Nederlandstalig' is added at start row = 2 (and rowspan = 4) while I've specified the start row = 3 of the added view.

Can anyone help me with this matter? Does GridLayout automatically take the first empty row or does it resize an empty row to 0 (I can recall having read something like that).

How can I fix this so when I add an item at start row 3, the item is starting at row 3 regardless of empty cells or rows? Is a TableLayout more suitable for this?